# After creating an NSMutableArray and adding objects, count shows as 0

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

The fast enumeration works, and shows the memory address for my 3 objects.  But a simple count on my brothersArray (brothersArray.count) comes up with 0.  I'm a bit of a noob.  What I am missing?

I'm not receiving any errors or warnings.  Everything appears to work fine.  I just can't figure out why my array.count comes up as zero.  Thanks in advance!

Here is my entire MasterViewController.m

```
//  MasterViewController.m
//  Matt_Bug
//
//  Created by Matthew Toto on 5/17/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Matthew Toto. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MPTBrothers.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Brothers";

    MPTBrothers *First = [[MPTBrothers alloc]initWithInfo:@"JP" age:37 height:5];
    MPTBrothers *Second = [[MPTBrothers alloc]initWithInfo:@"Matt" age:33 height:6];
    MPTBrothers *Third = [[MPTBrothers alloc]initWithInfo:@"Kevin" age:27 height:5];
    NSMutableArray *brothersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:First, Second, Third, nil];

    for (id brotherObjects in brothersArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", brotherObjects);
    }
    NSLog(@"The array count is %lu",brothersArray.count);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MPTBrothers *brotherCell = [self.brothersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = brotherCell.name;
    NSLog(@"BrotherCell Name = %@", brotherCell.name);

//    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

Here is my MPTBrothers.m

```
#import "MPTBrothers.h"

@implementation MPTBrothers

-(id)initWithInfo:(NSString *)name age:(int)age height:(int)height {
    if (self = [self init])
    _name = name;
    _age = age;
    _height = height;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors when you compile?

Comment: `NSLog()` First, Second, Third and brothersArray. BTW, by convention variables begin with a lowercase letter. Also the for statement is best as: `for (MPTBrothers *brotherObjects in brothersArray)`

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a problem in the code you've posted.

Comment: May be the problem is with your `MPTBrothers`?

Comment: Is the actual code with nothing missing? IF the three object addresses log the count has to be correct.

Comment: `NSLog(@"The array count is %lu",(unsigned long) (brothersArray.count));`

Comment: But that does not make a difference, just removes a warning on iOS, I ran sample code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried out your code, building my own version of `MPTBrothers`. Worked great. Wherever your problem is, it's not in what you've provided. Try publishing your `MPTBrothers` source.

Comment: I tried doing the same, it prints 3. Are you sure you are not doing some thing else?

Comment: I swear this didn't work last night.  I just tried it again (Xcode has since been restarted) and it worked.  WTH.  Sorry guys for the false alarm.  I really appreciate your help!